# AZure Data Factor - Data flow - aggregate

Tags: azure-data-factory

An Aggregate transformation in the ADF Data Flow gives me the wrong result.  Why??

Using Azure Data Factory, I want to count number of Projects in the SQL Database using Data Flow.
SO, create a data flow, set up the source, reading primary keys from the table
[image: set up source]

Looking at the preview data - seems correct, I get the List ..  There are 1600 items or so .. The list here looks large ... I can't see all 1600, but .. OK ...

[image: Preview data from Source]

So, then I add an "Aggregate" transformation
as follows
[image: Aggregate transformation settings]

And .. then checking the "Data preview" - I see that it only counted 1000 items.
[image]
Did it do
**Select top 1000 ?**
Or what ?  Please help ?

**P.S:**
If in the source settings I Specify the query as

```
select count(_id) as 'Count'
from [dbo].[Projects]
```

I will get the correct result in the source 'Data Preview" tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The count is shown as 1000 because in data flow debug settings, rows are limited to 1000 sample rows rather than taking the full data. This is the reason ADF is not able to count.

To increase the row limit,

- click the **debug settings** on the dataflow canvas toolbar.
- In General tab of dataflow debug dialog box, increase the row limit value- of source1 from 1000 to required value.
- Click Save.

[image: gif1]